# How to use pointer to split the string into two strings? C language

Tags: c, string, pointers

The function `char *my(char *s, int n)` takes a string `s` and shifts the characters of `s` by `n` places, causing the characters to wrap around the string.

For example, given the string "This is my Apple!" , a shift of n = 2 will result in

- String1: "Th"
- String2: "is is my Apple!"

if n<0 it will shift in negative direction.

Comment: You can use `strstr()`, if substring is found it will be returned.

Comment: Use [memcpy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy) ?

Comment: As far as I know, the function you describe does not exist in the usual libraries. The specification however reads as if you can use it to answer the question in the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `printf` to split a string. If you want the result in a `char *`, you have to allocate some memory and use `sprintf` instead.

Here is a example using `sprintf`and memory allocation to return a `char *`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *shift(char *string, int n)
{
    int len = strlen(string);
    char *shiftedString = malloc(len + 1);

    n %= len; // in case you shift over string length
    if (n < 0) n += len; // backward shift
    sprintf(shiftedString, "%s%*.*s", string + n, n, n, string);
    return shiftedString;
}

int main()
{
    char *result = shift("This is my Apple!", 2);
    printf("shifted string : %s\n", result);
    free(result);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: how to use return, instead of using printf

Comment: I've modified the function to return a `char*` instead of printing the result.

Answer (score 1):

the string is actually a char-array char[]
you could use the [`strlen`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strlen.htm) function in combination with a for loop like so.

You can put that in a function thus creating your own function that would shift letters based on input N.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char string[] = "This is my Apple!";
    //Initialize "n" before initializing the string variables.
    int n = 2;
    int len = strlen(string);
    char string1[n];
    char string2[len - n];

    for(int i = 0;i<len;i++){
        if(i<n){
            string1[i]=string[i];
        }else{
            string2[i-n]=string[i];
        }
    }
    printf("string = %s\n",string);
    printf("string1 = %s\n",string1);
    printf("string2 = %s\n",string2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1) Put `#include <string.h>` for `strlen`. 2) `char string1[n];` --> `char string1[n+1];` : +1 for null-terminator.

Comment: char string1[n];  Error: must have the constant value

Comment: there would be an error if you initialize "char string1[n]" before initializing "int n = 2", but if you look carefully at my code you would notice that that isn't the case.

Comment: It seems that @bob90937 is using a compiler before C99.